# How to access smarty library in third party folder using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

i just need a little help here about installing Smarty in Codeigniter.

What i did is:

1. Extract smarty, rename to smarty and put in third party folder
2. Enable smarty in autoload.php
3. Create templates folder in views (templates,templates_c)
4. Run sample page (In my case i run the default index which the welcome message)

The result is: 
**Unable to load the requested class: smarty**

In my autoload.php I added the smarty:

```
$autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'third_party','smarty');


/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Auto-load Libraries
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| These are the classes located in the system/libraries folder
| or in your application/libraries folder.
|
| Prototype:
|
|   $autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'xmlrpc');
*/

$autoload['libraries'] = array('smarty');
```

I just don't know where's my error. I hope you can help me. I am a beginner in smarty.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to create a library class to extend smarty and autoload that. In your `/application/library/` folder create a new file called `smartylib.php`

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

// path to SMARTY library
include APPPATH.'thirdparty/Smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';

class Smartylib extends Smarty {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

Then autoload it in your autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('smartylib');
```

You may be required to do some config stuff for Smarty in your construct. Take a look at the  Smarty Documentation on [**extending smarty**](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/installing.smarty.extended.tpl)

You will then be able to use it in your controller:

```
$this->smartylib->assign('name','Ned');
$this->smartylib->display('index.tpl');
```

Answer (score 0):

Further, if you like or need to use as

```
$this->smarty->assign('name', 'Ned');
```

Please CLONE the 'smartylib' object into 'smarty' on the `Controller __Consructor()` function

```
$this->smarty = clone $this->smartylib;
```